# How do I access datetime field formatter node values?

Tags: datetime

The DateTimeFormatterBase class is performing a ->setTimeZone incorrectly for my use case. How do I access the node values from where the $date passed to setTimeZone originated? Strange question I know, but I need to get to an entity reference field value to find the right time zone for the date.
Simple use case that I can't make work:
3 Fire Station nodes in Content Type FireHouses.
 
1 Content type Alarms with entity reference to FireHouses.
Station#, Address, City, Timezone
Station 1, 123 Main St, New York City, America/New_York
Station 1, 321 Any St, Chicago, America/Chicago
Station 1, 567 Hollywood, Los Angeles, America/Los_Angeles

Alarms come into all 3 stations at the same time (let's say just after midnight in New York) and Drupal sets Authored On field to same UTC time on all 3 Alarm nodes.

Views Report with Grouping by City:
New York:
  Fire at 987 street, 2019/01/25 12:01 am
   .
   .
Chicago:
  Medical Emergency, 2019/01/24 11:01 pm
   .
   .
Los Angeles:
   Fire at 567 Hollywood, 2019/01/24 09:01 pm
   .

This really simple use case/report fails because Drupal provides System Timezone, User Timezone, Field Display widget TZ (whole entity, not node level), Views TZ override and none apply here. 3 alarms, each in a different time zone but at the same time and I've found no way to override core functionality at the FormatterBase level because I can't traverse up (from $date) to the FireHouse entity level to get the correct TZ to provide to $date->setTimeZone function. Inside PHPStorm I can see the memory cache with node ids that I could use to get back to the FireHouse but I can't access them in code. My module must override core at this level so all displays of a date anywhere in the application are for the local time where the incident occurred.